# How to keep URL, but redirect content?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I would like to be able to rewrite a domainname.

Currently i'm using htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.mydomain.net%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Now, when users type 'http://mydomain.com' into the address bar, the page is redirected to 'http://www.mydomain.net'. But, at the same time, the address field is changed into the second one.

I would like to be able to serve different content but let the url for the user/client stay the same.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serve the content from somewhere else, you must use an internal rewrite. This is done automatically, when you have just an URL substitution path (i.e. no domain) and no `R` flag

```
RewriteRule ^this$ /that
```

When you get a request for `www.mydomain.com/this`, then the content from `www.mydomain.com/that` will be served to the client.

You can also use the request URL, or just part of it, in your target

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ /test.php?url=$0
```

See [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) and [mod_rewrite intro](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html) for details.